# Компиляция hadoop-java программ в solaris

Tags: java, map-reduce, solaris, компиляция, linux

Объясните, пожалуйста, опции в команде компиляции

```
javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

(зачем они нужны) на странице http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, опция -d как я понял создает папку для класса в программе WordCount.java, а зачем используется опция -classpath в данном случае и зачем указывается архив ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar?

Comment: @ivan31, как, кааааак можно работать с фреймворками не зная как работать с java??? Почитайте хотя бы java для чайников, я уверен что это даже там будет описано, это САМОЕ ПЕРВОЕ о чем пишут в любой книге по java.

Comment: @Viacheslav неа. В книгах для чайников по java пишут про синтаксис и могучее ООП. Про компилятор от силы пару раз упоминается.

Comment: Ну, про -classpath во многих учебниках пишут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)](/users/4705/ivan31) вам не надоело?

Рассказываю по порядку что происходит. Там написано примерно следующее:

> Взять компилятор Java (javac),
> запустить его на компиляцию класса
> WordCount.java причем, внешние ссылки
> разрешать за счет библиотеки
> `${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar`
> (предполагается, что переменные среды
> `HADOOP_HOME` и  `HADOOP_VERSION`
> определены. Скомпилированные объектные
> коды (файл `WordCount.class`) выкинуть в каталог
> `wordcount_classes`

Comment: @Barmaley, а что такое внешние ссылки?

Comment: смотрите в исходниках на `import org.apache.hadoop.*` - это и есть внешние ссылки.

не позорьтесь - возьмите любой учебник Java и прочитайте